# join query with group_concat, duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

my below query is not working as i accept  basically i am willing to fetch all the record for each doctor with their specialties by comma separated and also fetch each doctor appointments with specific month but the query  repeating  comma separated specialties.

```
select  d.doctorFName,d.doctorLName ,count(ap.appointmentID) totalap,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.speciality) specialities
FROM  tbl_doctors d
INNER JOIN  tbl_doctor_speciality  ds ON (d.doctorID = ds.doctorID)
INNER JOIN tbl_speciality  s ON (s.spID = ds.spID)
Inner join tbl_appointment ap on (ap.doctorID = d.doctorID)
Inner join tbl_patients p on p.patientID = ap.patientID 
GROUP BY d.doctorID
```

my this is working good with each doctor and their specialties by comma separated

```
select  d.doctorFName,d.doctorLName ,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.speciality) specialities
FROM  tbl_doctors d
INNER JOIN  tbl_doctor_speciality  ds ON (d.doctorID = ds.doctorID)
INNER JOIN tbl_speciality  s ON (s.spID = ds.spID)
GROUP BY d.doctorID
```

but when i add join for appointment its repeating specialties,below is my database,i hope you will understand data by query.where i doing wrong? and also how i can use

```
DATE_FORMAT(ap.appDate, '%Y-%m') = '2013-10'
```

with above query becuase itrs getting error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `DISTINCT` in group_concat, inner join for one to many will generate the Cartesian product so you will have the repeated values

```
select  d.doctorFName,d.doctorLName ,count(ap.appointmentID) totalap,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  s.speciality) specialities
FROM  tbl_doctors d
INNER JOIN  tbl_doctor_speciality  ds ON (d.doctorID = ds.doctorID)
INNER JOIN tbl_speciality  s ON (s.spID = ds.spID)
Inner join tbl_appointment ap on (ap.doctorID = d.doctorID)
Inner join tbl_patients p on p.patientID = ap.patientID 
GROUP BY d.doctorID
```

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid,how i can use DATE_FORMAT(ap.appDate, '%Y-%m') = '2013-10' with where cluase?

Comment: `ap.appDate >= '2013-10-01' AND ap.appDate < '2013-10-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`  Learn about DATETIME index range scans. But that's a different question.